# How to send mail using email of user from node in Google Appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

**TASK:**

1. I want to send an email to a receiver using the user's email ID who has installed the google form addon
2. I want to trigger this function from my backend after a certain condition is met.

**PROBLEM:**

1. I cannot call this function from my backend unless I execute the script as myself. Which I don't want

How to achieve this?

Here is what I have tried.
The issue is that when I deploy as img below and when I trigger doPost function from backend it does not run as it does not know from which users context script has to be run
[image]

Here is the code

```
function triggerdoPost() {
  var URL='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzM97wKyc0en6UrqXnVZuR9KLCf-UZAEpzfzZogbYApD9KChnnM/exec';
  var payload = {payloadToSend : 'mail@gmail.com'};
  var method = 'post'
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {method : method, payload: payload, headers: headers}).getContentText();
  Logger.log(response);
  return;
}
```

Been stuck for 3 days.
Any guidance is appreciated
TIA

Comment: Create this inside the addon itself. trigger inside the onInstall(). You can use the userproperties to set a bool if the email is send already..

Comment: Could you share your code to see what you tried so far? Sometimes it's best to share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @GabrielCarballo I have added a little code please have a look